# Angular how not to import all the dependencies in component unit tests each time

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli, angular7

I have a working app(when run `ng serve` all works fine)
however, when I run  `ng test` compiler complains about not recognizing directives/properties such as `Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` When I add

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SomeComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        .. other dependencies
    ]
```

what is the smart way not to add all the imports that I have already added in the `app.module` ?

UPDATE: I am talking about unit testing a component.

Comment: Have you imported ReactiveForms module from @angular/router package  ? Try adding this.

Comment: There's no smart way. Imports can be different from the module to the testbed (Http is one of those cases), the providers need to be mocked, and depending on your type of test, you might not require all the declarations. If you want to reduce the imports, then you have to reduce the module first.

Comment: This sounds like your module is trying to do too much. You could argue the unit test is telling you to refactor your code.

Comment: @Liam not arguing. possible. Just started with angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tests are **Independent** from your app.module. So you need to import all needed modules.

If you want, you can do a `shared.module.ts` where you have all the modules for test:

```
const MODULE_DEPENDENCIES = [
  TranslateModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  ScrollingModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: MODULE_DEPENDENCIES,
  exports: [
    ...MODULE_DEPENDENCIES
  ],
})

export class SharedModule {
  constructor() { }

  }
}
```

Comment: nice, I like it thanks. However, will keep it open for a while maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Of course. But keep in mind that, if you have a shared module for your test, you will import all of them, even the not needed one. It can be problematic if you want to assure the perfect condition of the component. So it depends which strategy you chose.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a SharedModule which holds all your directives etc

- see https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules for best practices (one of the most important, try to avoid defining services in SharedModules which also hold components

or just reuse the array of modules

basically

```
export const modules: any[] = [
  BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      modules,
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and in your test

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SomeComponent
      ],
      imports: modules
```

I don't know of another way.

But you can do the same with declarations and providersa and save some typing with that

Comment: why the downvote?
sharedmodule or a module array are the only way too do it
Care to explain whoever downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input', you will have to import following module/s under TestBed configuration.
 FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,  MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule

Ex: I have additional modules imported in my case and below is the sample code.

```js
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let component: SomeComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SomeComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, MatCardModule, MatIconModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatInputModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [SomeService]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  function setup() {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    const someService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(SomeService);

    return { fixture, component, someService };
    return { fixture, component };
  }

  it('should create app component', () => {
    const { component } = setup();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


});
```

Comment: the question was exactly ho to not declare "HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule, MatCardModule, MatIconModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatInputModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule" again

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by importing the module, where the tested component is declared in. This allows the test file to have access to the dependencies provided by the module.

I still need to separately import testing modules, for example `HttpClientTestingModule` and `RouterTestingModule`, in addition to the component's module, since the module doesn't use these. But this still reduces the amount of copy-paste needed and seems like a good approach to import only the needed modules instead of declaring everything in a shared module.

My module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TestedComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DirectivesModule,
        FormsModule,
        PipesModule,
    ],
})
export class TestedComponentModule { }
```

My test file:

```
describe('TestedComponent', () => {
    let component: TestedComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestedComponent>;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TestedComponent,
            ],
            imports: [
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                TestedComponentModule,
            ],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestedComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```